# Xamarin ListActivity onTouchEvent (or any other touch listener)

Tags: android, xamarin, touch-event, listadapter

I'm trying to learn Xamarin and as a very basic first app I'm trying to play around with a list adapter. the lists shows just well but I want to do things with the items in it like swiping etc. I tried the following code below but it seems like the OnTouchEvent is not being called (maybe because it's not attached to the view of the list but to something "below" it? when I tried using it in MainActivity it worked well). I managed to use OnListItemClick but it's not enough for me. How can I make the OnTouchEvent work or what other possibilities do I have to listen to touch event?

thanks

```
public class SomeList: ListActivity
{

    string[] someArr;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        someArr = getArr();

        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SwipeListView, someArr); 

    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already two years in Xamarin and never even heard of `ListActivity` lol :D My bad.

Comment: Post you xml, please

Comment: I don't hane an xml(i think...) for this activity. And if you didn't know it even exists then what other idiom I can use that does something equivalent?

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reasons you can use listview to start with.

`ListView` consists of the following parts:

> Rows – The visible representation of the data in the list.
>
> Adapter – A non-visual class that binds the data source to the list
>   view.
>
> Fast Scrolling – A handle that lets the user scroll the length of the
>   list.
>
> Section Index – A user interface element that floats over the
>   scrolling rows to indicate where in the list the current rows are
>   located.

To create simple list do the following:

create xml for your `listview` and `listview items`:

`ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`ListViewItem`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtName" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`Listview` needs an adapter to display items so we should create one:

```
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    List<string> _list;
    Activity _context;
    public ListAdapter(Activity context, List<string> list)
    {
        _context = context;
        _list = list;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItem, null);
        }

        TextView txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);

        var item = _list[position];

        txtName.Text = item.UserName;

        return view;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _list.Count;
        }
    }

    public override string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Activity` and set your adapter to `listview`:

```
ListView _listView;
ListAdapter _adapter;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.List);

    _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
    _listView.ItemClick += ItemClick;

    _adapter = new ListAdapter(this, myList);
    _listView.Adapter = _adapter;
}


    void ItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff on item click.
    }
```

Thats it.
For detailed tutorial check [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/)

More Links:
[Swipe To Refresh](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/SwipeToRefresh/)

For more complex functionalities and flexibility check [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/)

Comment: turns out ListAcitivity simply has a ListView field that can be used and there is no need to rewrite all this stuff